# Facet query will give wrong output on dynamicfield in solr

Tags: e-commerce, solrnet, facet

I have dynamicField as 'pa_mydynamicfieldname' in Solr 4.0

I have store value in this field as :

I have indexed my data by Encoding using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pa_mydynamicfieldname)
such as : 2.2+GHz+Intel+Pentium+Dual-Core+E2200

When i apply facet query to get result then output is as :

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="pa_mydynamicfieldname">
    <int name="2.2">1</int>
    <int name="2.5">1</int>
    <int name="core">1</int>
    <int name="dual">1</int>
    <int name="e2200">1</int>
    <int name="ghz">1</int>
    <int name="intel">1</int>
    <int name="pentium">1</int>
</lst>
```

Instead of this I want output as :

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="pa_mydynamicfieldname">
    <int name="2.2+GHz+Intel+Pentium+Dual-Core+E2200">1</int>
</lst>
```

how can do this in Solr while applying facet query ?

**Updated on 15-May-13**

From Schema, text field is defined as:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
```

And dynamic field is defined as:

```
<dynamicField name="pa_*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="false" />
```

We need it as multi-valued field, because a document may have multiple value defined for each product.

Please Help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to accomplish the behavior that you are desiring, you will need to change the fieldType for the dynamic field in your schema.xml. Currently, your `pa_mydyanmicfieldname` is probably defined as a `type="text_general"` and with `multivalued="true"`. So your field value is being split into tokens and these tokens are then being stored as multiple values. This is producing the behavior you show with multiple words/tokens being returned as facet values.

Since you want to store the original value as you submit it, please change your fieldType to just a plain old string and not multivalued:

```
 <dynamicField name="*_mydynamicfeldname" type="string" 
           indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Or you can alternately take advantage of the predefined string based dynamic field defined in  the example [schema.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_3/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup):

```
 <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
```

You will need to reindex your data after making this change to your schema.xml for new field types to be stored properly and reflected in the search results.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have updated question with additional information. I will try today again with changing type to string from text and update here. Thank you again.

Comment: Based on your updated question, you can turn on multivalued, in this case, having it be of type string is the key. Since the text value is what is causing it to be broken up into multiple entries (2.2, GHZ, etc.) for each single value.

Comment: Thanks, it works now by changing the type from 'text' to 'string'.

Comment: Does Solr perform full text search for "string" filed type?

Comment: No Solr does not perform full text search for "string" field type, the "StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim" from the Solr example schema.xml - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_3/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup